# Safari Not Resizing Background Image

Tags: css, safari, responsive-design, background-image

I am working on a responsive website. I have a div with a background image which I need to resize according to the window size. Chrome and Firefox are responding the way I want it to. Safari does resize but it stops resizing at a certain point. Anybody have any suggestions?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
<div style="max-height:1155px; width:auto;" id="content">
<p> Content goes here</p>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container{

position:relative;
margin:auto;
vertical-align:middle;
max-width:95%;
}

#content{

background-image:url(images/LoginScreen%20TEST.jpg);
background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
position:absolute;
max-width:95%;
-webkit-max-width:95;
text-align:center;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: FYI, you're missing the % after -webkit-max-width:95; but more importantly you do not need a vendor prefix for max-width. You should remove that.